# Conditional Calculation of Columns in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I have a dataset like the one shown below

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- data.frame(col.1 = 1:16,
                  col.2 = c("B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", 
                            "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A"),
                  col.3 = c(30, 60, 75, 105, 40, 80, -20, 60, -20, -60, 40,
                            -40,-105,-20,-20,-45),
                  col.4 = c(39.34775, 31.66806, 28.57107, 28.43085, 29.30417, 36.21187,
                            40.29794, 40.70641, 65.85152, 66.85943, 69.26766, 67.24402,
                            74.85330, 79.17230, 78.75405, 64.47038))
dat
```

I'm trying to reach the final column which looks like this:

```
dat.2 <- dat %>% 
  mutate(col.Final =  c(1180.43, 1900.08, 2142.83, 2985.24, 1172.17,
                        2896.95, -629.63, 2442.38, -655.37, -1966.11,
                        2770.71, -1460.48, -3833.76, -730.24, -730.24, 
                        -1643.04))
```

So far, I have tried using `mutate()` function to reach this point.

```
dat.1 <- dat %>% 
  mutate(col.5 = col.3*col.4) %>% 
  mutate(col.6 = cumsum(col.3)) %>% 
  mutate(col.7 = if_else(col.2 == 'B', col.6, col.6 - col.3),
         col.8 = col.3/col.7)
```

When I'm trying to reach the final column I'm not getting the same results.

```
dat.1 %>% 
  mutate(col.9 = if_else(col.2 == 'A', col.8*lag(cumsum(col.5)), col.5))
```

Note: This same calculation was done successfully using Excel's `SUMIFS()` function.

I'm Trying to get the same results with `R` instead.

I have seen some of the Q&A for similar posts but still stuck with the final calculation. In Excel, it felt as if iteration was performed for certain condition and then the next condition was executed. Though, not sure what was done using excel, I think, somehow this is possible using R as well. Just unable to figure out how to get that.

Any help would be appreciated at this point.

**Update:**

Values for `col.5` and `col.8` corresponding to `col.2`:

```
col.2 = c("B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "A", "B", 
          "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A")
col.5 <- c(1180.4325, 1900.0836, 2142.8302, 2985.2393, 1172.1668,
           2896.9496, -805.9588, 2442.3846, -1317.0304, -4011.5658,
           2770.7064, -2689.7608, -7859.5965, -1583.4460, -1575.0810, 
           -2901.1671)
col.8 <-c(1.00000000, 0.66666667, 0.45454545, 0.38888889, 0.12903226,
          0.20512821, -0.05128205, 0.13953488, -0.04651163, -0.14634146,
          0.10256410,-0.10256410, -0.30000000, -0.08163265, -0.08888889, 
          -0.21951220)
```

Verifying values Using Hand Calculation!

Calculations using `col.5` & `col.8`

for "B" from top :

`1180.43 + 1900.08 + 2142.83 + 2985.24 + 1172.17 + 2896.95 = 12277.7020`

for A after :

`12277.7020 x -0.05128205 = -629.6266509` .... the 1st desired value for A

for "B" after:

```
12277.720 - 629.6266509 = 11648.07535
11648.07535 + 2442.3846 = 14090.45995
```

for "A" after:

```
 14090.45995 x -0.04651163 = -655.37026 ... 2nd desired Value for A
```

for "A" after:

```
 14090.45995 - 655.37026 = 13435.08969
 13435.08969 x -0.14634146 = -1966.110641 ... 3rd desired value for A
```

and so on....

I hope this explains.

Comment: Are yo sure the logic is correct

Comment: The doubt is that do you have the same values for 'col.5' to 'col.8' while doing this in excel

Comment: Well, I'm unsure about the logic in `if_else` statement but did the same calculation using a calculator and I do get the answers. Take the `col. Final` values for ex.1180.43+1900.08+2142.83+2985.24+1172.17+                  2896.95 = 12,277.70. This value * col.8 value for A i.e `-0.05128205` = -629.63, then  12,277.70 - 629.63 = 11648.08, This 11648.08+2442.38 = 14,090.46. Now, 14,090.46*(-0.04651163) = -655.37 which is col.8 value for next A. So using hand calculation I verified that final col calculation was correct, but can't seem to get the same with R

Comment: yep, the values are the same, they may be rounded but close values till 2 decimal points are good to go.

Comment: The issue could be with the second argument `col.8*lag(cumsum(col.5))`.  Here, we are taking the `lag` of cumulative sum.  Can you check whether the values are right there i.e. check `dat.1 %>% mutate(newcol.5 = lag(cumsum(col.5)))` and see if that values should replace based on the condition

Comment: Yep, the values I'm getting are wrong here `lag(cumsum(col.5))` itself but is there any other logic that can be applied here to get the desired results.

Comment: Can you update your post with the expected values from that multiplication.  It may be that you have a different way of expressing the output